# jQuery: selecting both the current element and the children in a single statement?

Tags: jquery

i have a jquery code that requires me to apply same changes on an element , its children, and its children's children. I currently am doing it in 3 statements :

```
    $(this).animate();      
    $(this).children().animate();       
    $(this).children().children().animate();
```

where all three line perform same animation without queuing. is there any way to do it in just a single statement?

Comment: Try using `$(this).next('div').children('span')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about that?

```
$(this).find("*").andSelf().animate();
```